# Extract specific part from a file

Tags: shell-script

My Input file is xyz.txt which contains bellow text:

mp ofile test._GDFS_Lookup.Lookup_ReRun "$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/rerun_lookup.dat'

mp ofile All_other_Setups.RPT_REQ_ID'file:'"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/dtu_admin_test_lookup.dat'

I need this as **output**:
$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/rerun_lookup.dat

file:'"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/dtu_admin_test_lookup.dat

Comment: Please (a) format the question properly and (b) rewrite it such that "we" can comprehend what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat xyz.txt
mp ofile test._GDFS_Lookup.Lookup_ReRun "$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/rerun_lookup.dat'
mp ofile All_other_Setups.RPT_REQ_ID'file:'"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/dtu_admin_test_lookup.dat'

$ awk -F"[ :]" '{print $NF}' xyz.txt
"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/rerun_lookup.dat'
'"$AI_SERIAL_LOOKUP"'/dtu_admin_test_lookup.dat'
```